# Find articles that have certain keywords in supplementary material

Tags: publications, literature-search, supporting-information

I currently use Scopus or ISI Web of Science when looking for articles containing certain keywords in title or abstract, etc. But now I need to find articles that have certain keywords in the supplemetary material, any ideas about it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "supplementary material"? The more detailed is your question, the better answers you might get.

Comment: Supporting information

Comment: Depending on the journal, the supplementary material may simply not be indexed, even by services that index all of the main article text.  Supplementary material sometimes includes data files and other material that isn't reasonably possible to index anyway.